# Interaction between metalic nanoparticles and aggregation

Tags: physical-chemistry, synthesis, metal, materials, colloids

I can't find any publication to deal with aggregation of colloidal metalic nanoparticles. What type of interaction(s) is/are there between aqeous metalic nanoparticles which give(s) rise to aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

Metallic nanoparticles, considered as colloids, are attracted to each other by van der Waals forces. To prevent their aggregation, we normally use dispersant using electrostatic repulsion or steric hindrance to stabilize the colloids.